# Not getting the sum totals in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam working on an application with certain calculations. I need to show and sum up the totals of Total INR and Margin Field. When a user put a percentage in Add (%) it calculates certain things and show the margin. And at the end script has to show the sum totals. Its showing Nan as of now.

My script is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>  
        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
            function isNum(value)
            {
                return 123;
            }

            function calcTotals1()
            {
                var grandTotal = 0;
                var i = 0;

                while (document.forms['cart'].elements['add_percentage[]'][i])
                {
                    add_percentageObj = document.forms['cart'].elements['add_percentage[]'][i];
                    addon_valueObj   = document.forms['cart'].elements['addon_value[]'][i];
                    total_inr_valueObj   = document.forms['cart'].elements['total_inr[]'][i];

                    totalObj = document.forms['cart'].elements['add_value[]'][i];
                    marginObj = document.forms['cart'].elements['margin_for[]'][i];


                                if (isNaN(add_percentageObj.value)) {
                                    add_percentageObj = '';
                                }
                                if (isNaN(addon_valueObj.value)) {
                                    addon_valueObj = '';
                                }

                                if (add_percentageObj.value != 0) {
                                    totalObj.value = (((total_inr_valueObj.value * 1) * add_percentageObj.value / 100) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
                                    grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
                                    marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);
                                    margin_total = ((margin_total *1) + marginObj.value * 1);

                                } else if (addon_valueObj.value !=0) {
                                    totalObj.value = ((addon_valueObj.value * 1) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
                                    grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
                                    marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);
                                    margin_total = ((margin_total *1) + marginObj.value * 1);

                                } else {
                                    totalObj.value = ((addon_valueObj.value * 1) + total_inr_valueObj.value * 1).toFixed(3);
                                    grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat(totalObj.value);
                                    marginObj.value = ((totalObj.value * 1) - (total_inr_valueObj.value * 1)).toFixed(3);
                                    margin_total = ((margin_total *1) + marginObj.value * 1);

                                }

                                i++;
                            }

                            document.getElementById('grand_total').value = grandTotal.toFixed(3);
                            document.getElementById('margin_total').value = margin_total.toFixed(3);
                            //document.getElementById('total_inr1').value = total_inr1.toFixed(3);
                            //document.getElementById('margin_for').value = margin_for;


                            return;

                        }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="cart" class="single">
            <div align="center" class="base">
                <table width="100%" border=1 style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
                        <td colspan="6"><b>Terms and Cost</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Terms</td>
                        <td>Total INR</td>
                        <td>Add (%)</td>
                        <td>Add Value</td>
                        <td>Total Value</td>
                        <td>Margin</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">Export Charges</td>
                        <td width="75%"><input type="text" id="total_inr[]" name="total_inr[]" value="13263.984"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="add_percentage[]" name="add_percentage[]" value="" onchange="calcTotals1()"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="addon_value[]" name="addon_value[]" value="" onchange="calcTotals1()"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="add_value[]" name="add_value[]" value=""></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="margin_for[]" name="margin_for[]" value=""></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="25%">IATA Charges</td>
                        <td width="75%"><input type="text" id="total_inr[]" name="total_inr[]" value="16579.98"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="add_percentage[]" name="add_percentage[]" value="" onchange="calcTotals1()"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="addon_value[]" name="addon_value[]" value="" onchange="calcTotals1()"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="add_value[]" name="add_value[]" value=""></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="margin_for[]" name="margin_for[]" value=""></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input name="gTotal" id="grand_total" style="font-weight: bold" size="20" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type='text' style='font-weight: bold'  id='margin_total' name='margin_total' size='8' readonly /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At some point it must be converting your numbers to a string which is then showing up as "NaN" when you try and use logical operators on it. have you tried using breakpoints or console logging the value at different points to work out where the error lies?

Comment: I guess the problem lies in this line:                         
margin_total = ((margin_total *1) + marginObj.value * 1);

Comment: In console iam not finding any errors.

Comment: try margin_total = ((margin_total *1) + parseInt(marginObj.value) * 1);

Comment: margin_total is not initialized yet. Therefore you cannot perform (margin_total *1).

Comment: Yes Additionster is correct, well spotted. You're basically trying to do undefined *1 which will throw problems at you, initialise margin_total then try performing this again.

Comment: @ Additionster. Yes its working fine now. I have one more query. Is there a way i can show grandTotal on load. i mean with out triggering anything>?

Comment: @Vistari. I have one more query. Is there a way i can show grandTotal on load. i mean with out triggering anything?

Comment: You could just make a call to the calculate total function within the main body of javascript (inside the script tags) just call calcTotals1()

Comment: when i gave <script>calcTotals1();</script>. Its throwing an error document.forms.cart is undefined

Comment: put "calcTotals1()" after the function but before you close the </script> tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `parseInt()` to work really with integers instead of strings. If you read values from some html elements, you get these values as `string`. It also can cause wrong calculations. Just call `parseInt()` each time you read numeric value from html page element

Comment: Yes i will. Still a Novice and iam learning jquery. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: `parseInt()` is a function of `JavaScript` itself. As I know `jQuery` does not have any methods like this. If this helps you, please mark answer as the right answer for you

Comment: Already if u can read the above comments from Additionster, its been solved.